# How to implement javascript beforeunload event functionality for IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

As of 2021 IOS doesn't support beforeunload event, I need to show confirmation alert box before user loads the page. Page should only get reload when user confirms with continue action, if clicks on cancel page should not reload. I am trying with pagehide & pageshow event but not able to resolve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it definitely true that IOS does not support it? According to [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeunload it is supported.

Comment: yes you can check here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5